# How do I add an "L" to the end of an integer?

Tags: java, plugins, integer, long-integer, minecraft

I'm trying to add a L to the end of this integer and I get an error to make it a long. I need it to be in the form of an integer though...
Can someone please help me?
Here is my code:

```
int timeBetween = plugin.getConfig().getInt("timeBetweenSendsInTicks");
timeBetween = timeBetween + "L";
```

Although, remember, it must strictly be an **INTEGER**!

EDIT: I need it to be something that goes with this:

```
scheduler.scheduleSyncRepeatingTask(this, new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            @SuppressWarnings("unused")
            BukkitTask task = new Timer(JavaPlugin.getPlugin(GodSends.class), amountOfChest).runTaskTimer(JavaPlugin.getPlugin(GodSends.class), 20, timeBetweenChest);
            String startMSG = plugin.getConfig().getString("startMSG");
            getServer().broadcastMessage(startMSG);
        }
    }, 0L, timeBetween); //< this needs to have an L at the end, I have it set to 60000 in the config, but I cant seem to get the L after it.
```

Comment: How do you expect to assign a non-numeric character to a numeric type?  That doesn't make sense.

Comment: an integer can only a number. 'L' is not a number.

Comment: `L` is used in *Java integer literals* to denote the resulting type (long vs int), but is *not* part of the resulting (long) value. If you have an int and want to 'make' it a long (never-mind it will promote itself in most cases): `(long)some_int`.

Comment: Just pass the original `timeBetween`. It will be converted to `long` by compiler automatically. Explicitly adding `L` is unnecessary. By the way you also need to close the parenthesis at the end of `scheduleSyncRepeatingTask` call.

Comment: Do you mean cast to `long` type, add "L" as a string (meaning change the int to a string type and add L), *L* as in a Lagrangian (not int) or Length or some other representation of a number?

Answer (score 2):

It seems the API you're using `scheduler.scheduleSyncRepeatingTask()` expects the last two parameters to be of type `long`. Since, an `int` can implicitly fit into a `long`, passing `timeBetween` as it is will work just fine.

Same goes for the second parameter too. You can pass `0` instead of `0L` there as well. It works out the same. Basically, you're gaining nothing by explicitly passing a *long literal* here. They make sense in cases where you want to assign a `long` with a literal value that's outside of the integer's range.

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be trying to make an `int` variable into a `long` variable at runtime by putting an "L" 'at the end' of the integer.  This is not the correct way to do this.

Putting an L at the end of a numeric integer literal *within a java program* will cause the *compiler* to treat it as a `long` value instead of an `int` value.  But you aren't feeding a literal to the compiler, so the "L" notation doesn't help you here.

I think what you need is to *cast* your int to a long for passing to your method, whatever it is -- so instead of

```
}, 0L, timeBetween);
```

you should have

```
}, 0L, (long) timeBetween);
```